# Does directory match array variable

Tags: bash, wildcards, array

I'd like to check to see if a directory contains an array of file extensions. I'm on Ubuntu using Bash.

Something like :

```
files=$(ls $1/*)

extensions=$( txt pdf doc docx)

if [[ -e $files[@] contains $extenstions[@] ]] && echo "document exists" || 

echo "nothing found"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(*.txt *.pdf *.doc *.docx)
if [[ ${#files} -eq 0 ]]; then echo "nothing found"; fi
```

or

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
files=(*.+(txt|pdf|doc|docx))
if [[ ${#files} -eq 0 ]]; then echo "nothing found"; fi
```

If you need files from all subdirectories too:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob globstar
files=(**/*.+(txt|pdf|doc|docx))
if [[ ${#files} -eq 0 ]]; then echo "nothing found"; fi
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `nullglob`: If set, bash allows patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.
>
> `extglob`: If set, the extended pattern matching features are enabled. See below.
>
> `globstar`:  If  set,  the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.

[Extended globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing):

> `?(pattern-list)`: Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>
> `*(pattern-list)`: Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>
> `+(pattern-list)`: Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>
> `@(pattern-list)`: Matches one of the given patterns
>
> `!(pattern-list)`: Matches anything except one of the given patterns

Answer (score -1):

find all the files in directory:

```
 #find all types of files
 PDFS=`find . -type f | grep pdf |wc -l`
 TXTS=`find . -type f | grep txt |wc -l`
 DOCS=`find . -type f | grep doc |wc -l`
 DOCXS=`find . -type f | grep docx |wc -l`
 SUM=$(( PDFS + TXTS + DOCS + DOCXS ))
 if [[ $SUM=0 ]] ; then 
    echo "not found"
 else
    echo "Some document found"
```

You can do other stuff like that , such as how many documents of type pdf found , or something like that.

You can also use `grep -E` to write just one expression for counting all types of files , with OR (|) condition.  that will reduce to just one command.

Another easy option to count:

```
   numberoffiles=`find -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.doc" -o name "*.txt"`
```

Comment: `find -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.doc" -o name "*.txt"` etc...

Comment: yes , that is even more easy

Answer (score -1):

```
set   --                             ### init arg array
for e in txt pdf doc docx            ### outer loop for convenience
do    for  f in ./*."$e"             ### inner loop for files
      do   case  $f in (./\*"$e")    ### verify at least one match
           [ -e "$f" ];; esac &&     ### double-verify
           set  "$f" "$@"            ### prepend file to array
done; done                           ### double-done
```

When that completes all of the files will be in `$1` and `$2` and etc. The whole group can be referenced as a single string like `"$*"` or otherwise as a list of separate strings like `"$@"`. The count can be had in `"$#"`. And you can manipulate the arg array members with `set` *(as above)* or else w/ `shift`.

Answer (score -1):

Turn your list of extensions into a `@(…|…)` [wildcard pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
pattern='@('
for x in "${extensions[@]}"; do
  x=${x//"\\"//"\\\\"}; x=${x//"?"//"\\?"}; x=${x//"*"//"\\*"}; x=${x//"["//"\\["}
  pattern="$pattern$x|"
done
pattern="${pattern%\|})"
matches=(*.$pattern)
if ((${#matches[$@]})); then
  echo "There are matches"
fi
```

Alternatively (especially if you want to find files in subdirectories recursively), use `find`.

```
name_patterns=("(")
for x in "${extensions[@]}"; do
  x=${x//"\\"//"\\\\"}; x=${x//"?"//"\\?"}; x=${x//"*"//"\\*"}; x=${x//"["//"\\["}
  name_patterns+=(-name "*.$x" -o)
done
name_patterns[${#name_patterns[@]}]=")"
if [ -n "$(find dir "${name_patterns[@]}" | head -n 1)" ]; then
  echo "There are matches"
fi
```

Alternatively, use zsh.

```
matches=(*.$^extensions(NY1))
if ((#matches)); then
  echo "There are matches"
fi
```